PowerShell script doesn't work as it does in ISE
I've developed a program in ISE, but don't get the same behavior when running it from the command line (e.g., > .\script.ps1 -ProjectDirectoryPath .\project). Namely, exceptions are not redirected to an error log within try/catch and $Error is empty.
    # Loop start time
    $starttime = Get-Date

    foreach($thing in $things) {
        Write-Host "comment about $thing..."
        try {
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
            #does stuff
        } catch {
            $_.Exception | Out-File $ProjectDirectoryPath\error.log -Append
        }
    }

   # Print processing statistics and notify user if there were errors
    Write-Host "Processed $($things.Count) files in $(((Get-Date) - $starttime).Minutes) minute(s). There were $($Error.Count) error(s). Check error.log in the project directory to view them."

The output I get is essentially below, and no error.log is written to the project directory.
E: There was 1 error
Processed 1 files in 0 minute(s). There were 0 error(s). Check error.log in the project directory to view them.

I've tried changing the execution policies, both RemoteSigned and Unrestricted, but that doesn't seem to have helped the issue. I presume the issue comes down to the differences between the environments. What am I missing?

Try moving the "ErrorActionPreference" before the Try/Catch block. Also just what is in $Things you might try $Things.count to see if there is more than one thing. Hard to digest code with only small snippets. Try to create a Minimally reproducible example and post that..

How is the observed behavior different from the script executing successfully with no errors? Sounds like it's just working and you're expecting it not to....


First, let me offer the standard advice:

The PowerShell ISE is no longer actively developed and there are reasons not to use it (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell extension.

The difference in behavior you're seeing between the ISE and a regular PowerShell console is one of several differences that make the ISE problematic (whereas Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal exhibits no such differences.)
You're not showing what #does stuff stands for, but the implication is that you're calling an external (native) program that produces stderr output.
In the ISE, which uses the Windows PowerShell ISE Host PowerShell host (whereas PowerShell running in regular console windows / Windows Terminal uses ConsoleHost), stderr output is routed via PowerShell's error output stream, which means that, with $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" in effect, any stderr output is escalated to a (script-)terminating error, which can therefore be handled with a try statement.
However, this isn't appropriate, because stderr output - despite the stream's name (stderr, standard error) - isn't necessarily an indication of an error condition; console applications use it to write anything that isn't data to it, such as status information.
Success vs. failure of an external-program call should only be inferred from the process' exit code, as reflected in the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable.
By contrast, in a regular PowerShell console / in Windows Terminal, stderr is appropriately not routed via the error stream by default,[1] so the catch block is never triggered there.
Thus, use something like the following:
        try {
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
            # Some external-program call
            if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "External program 'foo' reported exit code $LASTEXITCODE." }
        } catch {
            $_.Exception | Out-File $ProjectDirectoryPath\error.log -Append
        }

If you also want to capture the stderr output yourself, you can append
2>> $ProjectDirectoryPath\error.log to your external-program calls.
If you're running v7.4+ of PowerShell 7, you may alternatively set preference variable $PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference to  $true, in which case any external-program call that reports a nonzero exit code triggers a non-terminating error indicating that fact, which - in combination with $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" - then triggers a (script-)terminating error that can be caught via a try statement - see this answer for details.

[1] Due to a bug in Windows PowerShell, this routing still occurs when a 2> redirection is involved. This problem has been fixed in PowerShell 7, though note that this routing still occurs in the context of remoting and jobs - albeit without being affected by $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" - see this answer for details.
